# Can you make a seed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know people make seeds because they know the numbers, the exact place and secret doors that lead to dungeons.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "make" a seed? Are you wanting to generate your own or find a seed for a specific world? You will need to add some more information so that we know exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Seeds are automatically generated when you create a new world, or used to generate a world similar to another. To me it sounds like you want to create a seed so specific that it generates a whole world for you, down to "the exact place of secret doors that lead to dungeons". This sounds way too complicated, and I'm not even sure it's practical, or even possible.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are asking "Can you design a world seed so it produces a world the way you want it?"  The answer to this question is **no**.

What most people do is *discover* a seed.  They start a game (either typing in a seed or letting the game generate one randomly) and then get to looking around and realize that their world is pretty awesome.  Whether they "guessed" at a seed or allowed the random generator to do its thing, they can now look up their world's seed (and starting settings) and share that information so that other people can generate their same starting world.

Only the starting world generation can be shared via a seed, not any changes you make (in the game or by using a mod or program).  Also remember that for a seed to work, other players need to be using the exact same generation settings as the seed's discoverer:  things like difficulty or resolution don't matter, of course;  but things like "Superflat" and "Generate Structures" must be set the same, and any mods that change world-gen (by adding new biomes or ores or plants or basically anything that spawns in the world instead of being crafted by the player) will completely invalidate any seeds discovered without using those exact same mods.

Comment: Should also note any mods that alter the world generation will make the same seed different between players, such as those which add new ores or biomes

Comment: I considered adding that, then felt it was extraordinarily obvious.  That said, you're right, I should probably still include it.